# Raspberry Pi ArchLinux ARM 64bit - WiFi card not detected

Tags: pi-3, wifi, kernel, 64-bit

I installed the new 64 bit kernel tarball of archlinux for Raspberry Pi 3.

I wanted to set it as access point but I didn't find any WiFi interface. Instead of 32 bits version, the WiFi chipset is not detected as well.

Has anyone else tried the new kernel ?

```
[root@alarm alarm]# iw list
[root@alarm alarm]# ifconfig 
eth0: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 10.42.0.240  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 10.42.0.255
        inet6 fe80::ba27:ebff:fef4:79b4  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether b8:27:eb:f4:79:b4  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 99  bytes 10516 (10.2 KiB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 90  bytes 12892 (12.5 KiB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

lo: flags=73<UP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING>  mtu 65536
        inet 127.0.0.1  netmask 255.0.0.0
        inet6 ::1  prefixlen 128  scopeid 0x10<host>
        loop  txqueuelen 1  (Local Loopback)
        RX packets 326  bytes 25778 (25.1 KiB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 326  bytes 25778 (25.1 KiB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

[root@alarm alarm]# uname -a
Linux alarm 4.9.0-2-ARCH #1 SMP Sat Dec 17 23:14:48 MST 2016 aarch64 GNU/Linux
```

Comment: Did you mean the on board WiFi is not detected?

Comment: yes. I don't use external wifi adapter

Comment: OK- I assume the WiFi / BT is connected via USB - Just like the LAN is. so I assume you can use `lsusb` to list the USB devices. You should see the something relating to BCM4334?

Comment: No scrap that.. the WiFi and BT is NOT connected to USB. Yea.. looks like its using I2C and UART.. meh?!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Built-in WiFi doesn't work at the moment, because it's maintained by Broadcom and available for 32-bit kernel only.

More information: [Can't Find Wireless Adapter on RPi3 (AARM64)](https://archlinuxarm.org/forum/viewtopic.php?f=65&t=11158)

Comment: Raspbian is 64bit isn't it?

Comment: No, it's 32. 64 bit doesn't get you much when your maximum RAM's 1 GB.